# How to sort numbers last in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, sql-order-by, postgresql-11

Found many related answers, but nothing that did this.

How to sort by numbers last:

```
AA
ZZ
11
55
```

And, preferably (but not necessary)

```
AA
A1
A2
```

PostgreSQL 11.9

Also, probably don't want to use a regex for performance reasons. Don't want to create an index either...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a regex is the right way to do this:

```
order by (col ~ '\d')::int, col
```

This puts first rows that contain no digit at all, then the remaining rows. Within each group, rows are sorted by ascending value.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a collation to do this for you and use it for this `order by`.

```
CREATE COLLATION digitslast (provider = icu, locale = 'en@colReorder=latn-digit');
CREATE COLLATION

with v (a) as (values ('123abc'), ('abc123'), ('ABC123')) 
select a from v order by a collate "digitslast";

   a
--------
 abc123
 ABC123
 123abc
(3 rows)

with v (a) as (values ('123abc'), ('abc123'), ('ABC123')) 
select a from v order by a; 
   a    
--------
 123abc
 abc123
 ABC123
(3 rows)
```